# Is there any way to rand between these four letters "B,C,M,P" in Excel?

Tags: excel-formula

I figured this out

```
=CHOOSE(RANDBETWEEN(1,4),"B","C","M","P")
```

But is there an alternative method to rand between these letters?
Thanks ~

Comment: do a rand from 1-4 (0-3?) and use the result as an index to an array with bcmp stored in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Method: 1**

```
=INDEX({"B","C","M","P"},1,RANDBETWEEN(1,4))
```

**Method 2:**

```
=CHAR(INDEX({66,67,77,80},1,RANDBETWEEN(1,4)))
```

Comment: You should use `INT(RAND()*4+1)` or `RANDBETWEEN(1,4)`. The way you have it now `INT(RAND()*5)` gives you 0,1,2,3,4 all with equal probabilities where both 0 and 1 are "B", so "B" is twice as likely as the other letters.

Comment: Updated per your suggestion!